# A (non-convex) minimization quadratic programming problem with d constraints

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming

Minimize $0<\omega_{dd}<2$ subject to
$$\sum_{j=1}^{d}(\omega_{dj} - \omega_{ij})^{2} \geq 4, i=0,1,...,d-1,$$
where $-2<\omega_{ij}<2$ is known for $0 \leq i \leq d-1$ and $1 \leq j \leq d$, and $-2<\omega_{dj}<2$ may vary for $1 \leq j \leq d$.

---

I happen to know that the matrix of $\omega_{ij}$'s for $1 \leq i,j \leq d$ is lower triangular (and we can set also set $\omega_{0,j}=0,\forall 1 \leq j \leq d$ and $\omega_{1,1}=2,\omega_{1,j}=0,\forall j>1$) and $\omega_{ij}>0$ for $d<8$, which may be helpful for choosing a technique (I'm also interested generally when it is not lower triangular as well). I keep coming back to this problem for applications in geometry research and am not an optimization/programming expert. Does anyone have a way to program this quadratic program, or have an idea for techniques or algorithms I could apply from the theory of optimization or quadratic programming?

Comment: At first look, your quadratic constraints are non-convex, that probably makes it hard to solve this problem (unless some nice simplification happens)...

Comment: It seems to me that choosing $\omega_{dj}$ very large for $j<d$ ensures the constraints are satisfied, so that you can accommodate them with arbitrarily low $\omega_{dd}$.